# How to detect shell options enabled

Tags: linux, bash, shell

[`set`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html) allows tweaking shell execution, by enabling some features. Some of the most popular are:

```
set -e   # exit on error
set -x   # print executed commands
```

Is there a way within a script to detect currently enabled features?

In my particular case I would like to know if the `set -x` was called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [the `$-` variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-_002d):

```sh
$ echo $-
himBCHs

$ set -e
$ set -x

$ echo $-
ehimxBCHs
^   ^
```

So:

```sh
if [[ $- == *x* ]]; then
    echo "xtrace is set"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks that answers my question. I've got a sub-questions. 

[1] Since `$-` dumps all of shell enabled options using appropriate letters, it should be possible to re-establish all options by iterating over saved string from `$-` and `eval`ing `set` with each option, one by one. Am I correct?

[2] Is there a way to apply all of the options at once, other way than iterating described above?

Comment: You could do `opts=$(do_stuff_with "$-"); set "-$opts"` but some shell options cannot be set with `set`, such as `-i`. In a loop: `while IFS= read -r -n1 opt; do do_something_with "$opt"; done < <(printf '%s' "$-")`

Comment: Or `opts="$-"; for ((i=0;i<${#opts};i++)); do echo do_stuf_with "${opts:i:1}"; done`

Comment: You may be surprised how much slower that can be: https://github.com/glennj/exercism.io/blob/main/_mentor_notes/bash.md#performance-impact-of-string-length

Answer (score 1):

The command `set -o` prints all the configured bash options.

Answer (score 1):

The builtin `shopt` can probably show what you wanted.

In man bash

```
errexit Same as -e
```

Now

```
help shopt
```

Output

```
shopt: shopt [-pqsu] [-o] [optname ...]
    Set and unset shell options.
    
    Change the setting of each shell option OPTNAME.  Without any option
    arguments, list each supplied OPTNAME, or all shell options if no
    OPTNAMEs are given, with an indication of whether or not each is set.
    
    Options:
      -o        restrict OPTNAMEs to those defined for use with `set -o'
      -p        print each shell option with an indication of its status
      -q        suppress output
      -s        enable (set) each OPTNAME
      -u        disable (unset) each OPTNAME
    
    Exit Status:
    Returns success if OPTNAME is enabled; fails if an invalid option is
    given or OPTNAME is disabled.
```

---

```
shopt -qo errexit

echo $?
```

It returns `1` if disabled or `0` if enabled.

Now to have an actual test.

```
if shopt -qo errexit; then
  printf 'errexit is enabled!\n'
fi
```

Or if you want to negate use the bang `!`

```
if ! shopt -qo errexit; then
  printf 'errexit is disabled!\n'
fi
```